# How to search using jQuery and SQL database in ASP.NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and tried to search a SQL database using ajax jQuery but encountered an error through the code I am using. The columns of the data table are displayed as "undefined".

Please help me solve this error.

This is my code - controller:

```cs
public JsonResult SearchBiodataJson(string SearchText)
{
    List<BiodatalistVM> list = _context.BiodataA
        .Where(x =>
            x.SurName.Contains(SearchText)
            ||
            x.OtherName.Contains(SearchText)
        )
        .Select(p => new BiodatalistVM
        {
            StaffId   = p.StaffId,
            SurName   = p.SurName,
            OtherName = p.OtherName,
            MDA       = p.MDA,
        })
        .ToList();

    return Json(list);
}
```

My view

```
    <input type="text" id="SearchText" class="form-control col-md-3" />
    
    <tbody id="tblBiodata">
@if(ViewBag.BiodataList != null)
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.BiodataList)
    {  
        <tr>
            <td>@item.StaffId</td>
            <td>@item.SurName</td>
            <td>@item.OtherName</td>
            <td>@item.MDA</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SearchText").on("keyup", function() {
        var searchtext = $("#SearchText").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/BiodataModels/SearchBiodataJson?SearchText=" + searchtext,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#tblBiodata").html("");

                if (result.length == 0) {
                    $("#tblBiodata").append("<tr><td colspan='4'>No Record Matched</td></tr>")
                }
                else {
                    $.each(result, function(index, value) {
                        var data = "<tr><td>" + value.StaffId + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.SurName + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.OtherName + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.MDA + "</td>";

                        $('#tblBiodata').append(data);
                    })
                } // if
            } // success
        }) // ajax
    }); // on #SearchText keyup
}); // ready
```

Comment: Double-check that the proper field name is not e.g. "staffId" (instead of "StaffId"). The JSON serializer that your controller uses might be configured to use camelCase instead of PascalCase

Comment: Along those lines, it will help people help you if you include a copy of the HTTP response that your jQuery code receives. You can see that in the "Network" tab of Chrome DevTools or similar

Comment: Are you sure it's a `post` and not a `get` method that your jQuery call should be doing? From the looks of `SearchBiodataJson` it doesn't seem like it would be a `post` method.

Comment: HTTP response                                                                                            
  StaffId         SurName         OtherNam       MDA
undefined undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined undefined
undefined undefined undefined undefined

Comment: Your jQuery code doesn't have a `</tr>` and your posted Razor is missing the `<table>` opening tag. Also, _you don't need **jQuery at all** for this_.

Comment: table and table header has opening and closing tags